# How to add easily button to my JavaFX TableView?

Tags: button, javafx, tableview

I have got two questions.
1-) I have got a JavaFX tableView screen and need to add a cancel button there. I prepared my screen via fxml file, added columns in fxml. Four columns will be used to show data and last column (fifth column)will be used to delete this record. I need to add this button via fxml. How can I add button? My fxml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<TableView fx:id="appointmentsTable" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="appointmentList.AppointmentListController">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="105.0" text="Randevu Günü">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="appointmentDay"/>
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>

    <TableColumn prefWidth="111.0" text="Randevu Saati" >
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="appointmentClock"/>
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>

    <TableColumn prefWidth="112.0" text="Randevu Sahibi">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="appointmentOwner"/>
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>

    <TableColumn prefWidth="122.0" text="Randevu Doktoru" >
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="appointmentDoctor"/>
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>

    <TableColumn prefWidth="69.0" text="İptal Et" >
    </TableColumn>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

2-) As I said that button will delete the record but I need the row id. How can I pass this id to the button action?
My controller class is like this:

```
    package appointmentList;

import connection.OpenConnection;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import pojos.Appointments;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 * Created by ilkaygunel on 04/08/16.
 */
public class AppointmentListController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableView appointmentsTable;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         ObservableList<Appointments> data =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(getTakenAppointments());
        appointmentsTable.setItems(data);
    }

    public List<Appointments> getTakenAppointments(){
        List<Appointments> appointmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        OpenConnection openConnection = new OpenConnection();
        Connection connection = openConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement getTakenAppointmentsPreparedStatement=null;

        try {
            getTakenAppointmentsPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM appointments");
            ResultSet resultSet = getTakenAppointmentsPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                appointmentsList.add(new Appointments(resultSet.getInt("appointmentId"), resultSet.getDate("appointmentDay"),resultSet.getString("appointmentClock"),
                        resultSet.getString("appointmentDoctor"),resultSet.getString("appointmentOwner")));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("An Error Occured! Error is:"+e);
        }
        return appointmentsList;
    }
}
```

Appointments pojo class:

```
    package pojos;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by ilkaygunel on 04/08/16.
 */
public class Appointments {
    int appointmentId;
    Date appointmentDay;
    String appointmentClock;
    String appointmentDoctor;
    String appointmentOwner;

    public Appointments(int appointmentId,Date appointmentDay,String appointmentClock,String appointmentDoctor,String appointmentOwner){
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
        this.appointmentDay = appointmentDay;
        this.appointmentClock = appointmentClock;
        this.appointmentDoctor = appointmentDoctor;
        this.appointmentOwner = appointmentOwner;
    }

    public int getAppointmentId() {
        return appointmentId;
    }

    public void setAppointmentId(int appointmentId) {
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
    }

    public Date getAppointmentDay() {
        return appointmentDay;
    }

    public void setAppointmentDay(Date appointmentDay) {
        this.appointmentDay = appointmentDay;
    }

    public String getAppointmentClock() {
        return appointmentClock;
    }

    public void setAppointmentClock(String appointmentClock) {
        this.appointmentClock = appointmentClock;
    }

    public String getAppointmentDoctor() {
        return appointmentDoctor;
    }

    public void setAppointmentDoctor(String appointmentDoctor) {
        this.appointmentDoctor = appointmentDoctor;
    }

    public String getAppointmentOwner() {
        return appointmentOwner;
    }

    public void setAppointmentOwner(String appointmentOwner) {
        this.appointmentOwner = appointmentOwner;
    }
}
```

Comment: To place a button in the cells you need a cell factory, which you can't create in FXML.

Comment: @James_D Surely I need this info. I was searching a way via fxml untill I see your comment. Thank you so much.